# What analog for separator in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I have an SQL-request, working correct in H2 DB:

```
update task_display td
set comments = (
    select group_concat(co.text separator '\n\n')
    from comments co
             left join ticket ti on co.ticket_id = ti.id
    where td.ticket_id = ti.id
    );
```

As we see, I use `separator` to separate text. What analog of this query for Oracle database?

UPD: While using script

```
update task_display td
    set comments = (select listagg(co.text, '\n\n') within group (order by co.id)
                    from comments co
                    where td.ticket_id = co.ticket_id
                   );
```

I reseive this error:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your strings are big enough to store the values:

```
update task_display td
    set comments = (select listagg(co.text, '\n\n') within group (order by co.id)
                    from comments co
                    where td.ticket_id = co.ticket_id
                   );
```

I don't see a need to `join` to `ticket` in either database.

The `order by co.id` is because `listagg()` requires an ordering.  I am guessing there is a column with that name, but any column can be used.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов . . . As I stated in the answer *assuming your strings are big enough*. Oracle limits strings to 2000 characters.  You can only do what you want with a CLOB.  And I don't think I would recommend that.